# Special Stacked Bar Chart R ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, data-visualization

Can you help me make the following bar chart in R? I have some simplified dummy data that i am using to recreate, and then my plan is to manipulate the data in the same way. No need to do the abline. The most important parts are the waterfall aspect.

```
   ï..labels value
1      start   100
2   january    120
3    febuary   140
4      march   160
5      april   180
6        may   130
7       june   140
8       july   170
9     august   160
10 september   180
11   october   190
12  november   210
13  december   200
14       end   200
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This gets you the waterfall effect:

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- 
  tibble::tribble(
    ~month, ~month_name, ~value,
     1,     "start", 100,
     2,   "january", 120,
     3,   "febuary", 140,
     4,     "march", 160,
     5,     "april", 180,
     6,       "may", 130,
     7,      "june", 140,
     8,      "july", 170,
     9,    "august", 160,
    10, "september", 180,
    11,   "october", 190,
    12,  "november", 210,
    13,  "december", 200,
    14,       "end", 200
  ) %>% 
  mutate(
    type = case_when(
      month == min(month) ~ "Initial",
      month == max(month) ~ "Final",
      value > lag(value) ~ "Increase",
      TRUE ~ "Decrease"
    ),
    finish = value,
    start = if_else(month == max(month), 0, replace_na(lag(value), 0))
  )

df %>% 
  ggplot(aes(xmin = month - 0.3, xmax = month + 0.3, ymin = start, ymax = finish, fill = type)) +
  geom_rect() +
  scale_x_continuous(
    breaks = 1:14,
    labels = df %>% select(month_name) %>% pull()
  ) +
  theme(
    axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1),
    legend.position = "none"
  )
```

You should be able to take care of the formatting and colors from here ;)

[image]